# READ TABLE WITH TABLE KEY does not find record

Tags: abap

I'm trying to use the class `/ui5/cl_json_parser` for parsing a JSON string.

The following code snippet reproduces the problem:

```
REPORT ztest_json_parse.

DATA: input TYPE string,
      output TYPE string,
      json_parser TYPE REF TO /ui5/cl_json_parser.


input = '{"address":[{"street":"Road","number":"545"},{"street":"Avenue","number":"15"}]}'.
CREATE OBJECT json_parser.

json_parser->parse( input ).
json_parser->print( ).

output = json_parser->value( path = '/address/1/street' ).

WRITE output.
```

The `print` method shows the correct parsed JSON string, but the `output` variable is always empty.

I have traced the code down to the method `VALUE` of the class `/UI5/CL_JSON_PARSER`, at line 15, which contains:

```
read table m_entries into l_entry with table key parent = l_parent name = l_name.
```

In the debugger, I can see that `l_parent = '/address/1'` and `l_name = 'street'`, and that the internal table `m_entries` contains a record with `parent = '/address/1'` and `name = 'street'`. Nevertheless the `READ` statement always returns `sy-subrc = 4` and does not find anything.

Can anyone help?

Comment: In my 7.52 SP00, I can easily reproduce your steps exactly as you explained, except that I get `sy-subrc 0` and the method `VALUE` returns `Road`. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you very much for testing. My environment is 7.31 SP09. There is probably a bug in ABAP in my version.

Comment: the code as presented returns Road . Works for me too.

Answer (score 1):

First: Do not use `/ui5/cl_json_parser` class, it is intended for **internal use** ONLY and has no reliable documentation

[image]

Secondly, here is the sample how you can fetch street value from the first element of your JSON:

```
DATA(o_json) = cl_abap_codepage=>convert_to( '{"address":[{"street":"Road","number":"545"},{"street":"Avenue","number":"15"}]' ).
DATA(o_reader) = cl_sxml_string_reader=>create( o_json ).

TRY.
    DATA(o_node) = o_reader->read_next_node( ).
    WHILE o_node IS BOUND.
      DATA(op) = CAST if_sxml_open_element( o_node ).
      LOOP AT op->get_attributes( ) ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<a>).
        DATA(attr) = <a>->get_value( ).
      ENDLOOP.
       IF attr <> 'street'.
         o_node = o_reader->read_next_node( ).
       ELSE.
         DATA(val) = CAST if_sxml_value_node( o_reader->read_next_node( ) ).
         WRITE: '/address/1/street =>', val->get_value( ).
         EXIT.
       ENDIF.
    ENDWHILE.
  CATCH cx_root INTO DATA(e_txt).
ENDTRY.
```

As far as I know, there is no class in ABAP that allows fetching single JSON attributes like XPath.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly agree with Suncatcher on avoid  UI5 Json parser.
If you dont control/know the structure of the source data, Suncatchers answer is good.

However, 
if you know the basic structure of the source JSON and you must, if you plan to access the first address row, fieldname street .
AND you can have the source provided using **uppercase** variable names then you can use the so called **identity transformation**.

```
types: begin of ty_addr,
     street type string,
     number type string,
     end of ty_addr.
types ty_addr_t type STANDARD TABLE OF ty_addr.

 DATA: input TYPE string,
       ls_addr TYPE ty_addr,
       lt_addr type ty_addr_t.

input = '{"ADDRESS":[{"STREET":"Road","NUMBER":"545"},{"STREET":"Avenue","NUMBER":"15"}]}'.

CALL TRANSFORMATION id SOURCE XML input
                           RESULT address = lt_addr.

 read table lt_addr index 1 into ls_addr.
 WRITE ls_addr-street.
```